# kivy: badly aligned widgets

Tags: layout, kivy

Example code fragment from a base class:

```
def build_extra_content(self):
    grp = 'choice_dialog'
    extra_content = GridLayout(cols=2)
    lb_width = self.width - 2 * self.choice_height
    for choice in self.choices:
        cb = CheckBox(group=grp,
                      size_hint=(None, None), size=(self.choice_height, self.choice_height))
        lb = Label(markup=True, text=choice, halign='left', valign='middle',
                   size_hint=(None, None), size=(lb_width, self.choice_height))
        lb.texture_size = (lb_width, self.choice_height)
        extra_content.add_widget(cb)
        extra_content.add_widget(lb)
        # TODO: check the checkbox when the label is touched.
        def _lb_press(*args):
            print(args)
        cb.bind(on_touch_down=_lb_press)

    return extra_content
```

The content is displayed in this dialog:

[image]

I have two questions. First: why the text is aligned to the center? I have already set absolute sizes for both the label and its texture size, and set halign='left'. But the text is still aligned to the center. Why?

Second: I wanted the labels to be clickable/touchable. E.g. the checkboxes should be selected by touching their corresponding labels. Whenever I click on a single label or checkbox, this is printed:

```
(<kivy.uix.checkbox.CheckBox object at 0x0B2C01B8>, <MouseMotionEvent button="left" device="mouse" double_tap_time="0" dpos="(0.0, 0.0)" dsx="0.0" dsy="0.0" dsz="0.0" dx="0.0" dy="0.0" dz="0.0" grab_current="None" grab_exclusive_class="None" grab_list="[]" grab_state="False" id="mouse3" is_double_tap="False" is_mouse_scrolling="False" is_touch="True" is_triple_tap="False" opos="(644.0, 379.0)" osx="0.503125" osy="0.47375" osz="0.0" ox="644.0" oy="379.0" oz="0.0" pos="(644.0, 379.0)" ppos="(644.0, 379.0)" profile="['pos', 'button']" psx="0.503125" psy="0.47375" psz="0.0" push_attrs="('x', 'y', 'z', 'dx', 'dy', 'dz', 'ox', 'oy', 'oz', 'px', 'py', 'pz', 'pos')" push_attrs_stack="[]" px="644.0" py="379.0" pz="0.0" shape="None" spos="(0.503125, 0.47375)" sx="0.503125" sy="0.47375" sz="0.0" time_end="-1" time_start="1507722998.229789" time_update="1507722998.229789" triple_tap_time="0" ud="{}" uid="3" x="644.0" y="379.0" z="0.0">)
(<kivy.uix.checkbox.CheckBox object at 0x0B5FC2D0>, <MouseMotionEvent button="left" device="mouse" double_tap_time="0" dpos="(0.0, 0.0)" dsx="0.0" dsy="0.0" dsz="0.0" dx="0.0" dy="0.0" dz="0.0" grab_current="None" grab_exclusive_class="None" grab_list="[]" grab_state="False" id="mouse3" is_double_tap="False" is_mouse_scrolling="False" is_touch="True" is_triple_tap="False" opos="(644.0, 379.0)" osx="0.503125" osy="0.47375" osz="0.0" ox="644.0" oy="379.0" oz="0.0" pos="(644.0, 379.0)" ppos="(644.0, 379.0)" profile="['pos', 'button']" psx="0.503125" psy="0.47375" psz="0.0" push_attrs="('x', 'y', 'z', 'dx', 'dy', 'dz', 'ox', 'oy', 'oz', 'px', 'py', 'pz', 'pos')" push_attrs_stack="[]" px="644.0" py="379.0" pz="0.0" shape="None" spos="(0.503125, 0.47375)" sx="0.503125" sy="0.47375" sz="0.0" time_end="-1" time_start="1507722998.229789" time_update="1507722998.229789" triple_tap_time="0" ud="{}" uid="3" x="644.0" y="379.0" z="0.0">)
(<kivy.uix.checkbox.CheckBox object at 0x0B5F3768>, <MouseMotionEvent button="left" device="mouse" double_tap_time="0" dpos="(0.0, 0.0)" dsx="0.0" dsy="0.0" dsz="0.0" dx="0.0" dy="0.0" dz="0.0" grab_current="None" grab_exclusive_class="None" grab_list="[]" grab_state="False" id="mouse3" is_double_tap="False" is_mouse_scrolling="False" is_touch="True" is_triple_tap="False" opos="(644.0, 379.0)" osx="0.503125" osy="0.47375" osz="0.0" ox="644.0" oy="379.0" oz="0.0" pos="(644.0, 379.0)" ppos="(644.0, 379.0)" profile="['pos', 'button']" psx="0.503125" psy="0.47375" psz="0.0" push_attrs="('x', 'y', 'z', 'dx', 'dy', 'dz', 'ox', 'oy', 'oz', 'px', 'py', 'pz', 'pos')" push_attrs_stack="[]" px="644.0" py="379.0" pz="0.0" shape="None" spos="(0.503125, 0.47375)" sx="0.503125" sy="0.47375" sz="0.0" time_end="-1" time_start="1507722998.229789" time_update="1507722998.229789" triple_tap_time="0" ud="{}" uid="3" x="644.0" y="379.0" z="0.0">)
```

Actually it doesn't matter where I click. Even if I click outside the GridLayout, always all labels will trigger the touch event. But why? I only want the one under my finger.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First: why the text is aligned to the center? I
>   have already set absolute sizes for both the label and its texture
>   size, and set halign='left'. But the text is still aligned to the
>   center. Why?

You're setting `texture_size`, but you [should](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html#text-alignment-and-wrapping) set `text_size` instead.

> Second: I wanted the labels to be clickable/touchable. E.g. the
>   checkboxes should be selected by touching their corresponding labels.
>   Whenever I click on a single label or checkbox, this is printed:

In Kivy every widget receive touch event. You [should](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/inputs.html#touch-events) check if touch happened inside your label manually:

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        # The touch has occurred inside the widgets area. Do stuff!
        pass
```

Comment: The first question is answered 100%. About the second question: I have tried to use collide_point, but it does not work. The main window has a popup inside, then it has some boxlayouts, then a ScrollView, and inside the ScrollView there are these labels. I'm not sure how to convert the touch position coordinates before checking the collide point.

Comment: When your widget uses some translations/context manipulation (relative layout/scrollview…) you may need to use `Widgets` `to_local`, `to_widget`, `to_screen` methods to convert the coordinates to the correct coordinate system. I don't see any code mandating that in what you posted, but maybe we don't have the whole story.

Comment: Finally I could make it work. I had to apply these conversions twice because the scrollview was inside a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to your second question.

## Note

> By default, touch events are dispatched to all currently displayed
> widgets. This means widgets receive the touch event whether it occurs
> within their physical area or not.
>
> In order to provide the maximum flexibility, Kivy dispatches the
> events to all the widgets and lets them decide how to react to them.
> If you only want to respond to touch events inside the widget, you
> simply check:

## Example

```
class ProjectSelectButton(Button):
    def click_on_button(self, instance, touch, *args):
        print(instance)
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            if touch.button == 'right':
                print(self.id, "right mouse clicked")
            elif touch.buttom == 'left':
                print(self.id, "left mouse clicked")
            return True
        return super(ProjectSelectButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```